# Matrix Multiplication Issues in C

Tags: c, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I'm making a matrix multiplication calculator in C. When I run it, spews out many numbers and results in this:

```
57736 segmentation fault
```

Where did I write wrong? Here is the code I wrote:

```
int Mtx1row, Mtx1col, Mtx2row, Mtx2col, c, d, e;
int first[10][10], second[10][10], mult[10][10];
```

Get 1st Matrix row and col

```
  printf("First Matrix: # of row and col?\n");
  scanf("%d%d", &Mtx1row, &Mtx1col);
```

Get 2nd Matrix row and col

```
  printf("Second Matrix: # of row and col?\n");
  scanf("%d%d", &Mtx2row, &Mtx2col);
```

Compare 1st Matrix col vs 2nd Matrix row

```
  if (Mtx1col != Mtx2row){
    printf("Mtx1col != Mtx2row (x _ x)\n");
    return 1;
  }
```

Get elements of first matrix

```
  printf("Enter elements of First Matrix: \n");
  for (c = 0; c < Mtx1row; c++)
  for (d = 0; d < Mtx1col; d++)
  {
    printf("\tEnter element %d%d: ", c+1, d+1);
    scanf("%d", &first[c][d]);
  }
```

Get elements of second matrix

```
printf("Enter elements of Second Matrix: \n");
  for (c = 0; c < Mtx2row; c++)
  for (d = 0; d < Mtx2col; d++)
  {
    printf("\tEnter element %d%d: ", c+1, d+1);
    scanf("%d", &second[c][d]);
  }
```

Multiply Matrix 1 and 2 and store into Matrix Product

```
  for (c=0; c < Mtx2row; c++){
    for (d=0; d < Mtx2col; d++){
      for (e=0; e < Mtx1col; e++){
        mult[c][d] += first[c][d] * second[d][e];
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You don't show any part of the code that allocates those matrices not any code that would "spew out" anything. Where did the debugger say the crash happened?

Comment: You wrote more code than that. You are making assumptions where your bug is. Where do these arrays come from?

Comment: Always check the return value of scanf

Comment: I suppose you check that the user doesn't input sizes above 10?

Comment: Have you stepped through this with a debugger? If you did you would know what values of Mtx1row, Mtx1col etc. were being used.

Comment: Did you remember to initialize the result matrix? Did you remember to check that `Mtx1col == Mtx2row`?

Comment: @4386427 Looks like values are changed: `Enter element 11: 1
  Value is: 1467740048
 Enter element 12: 2
  Value is: 1467740052` And I added code above that compares Mtx1col and Mtx2row.

Comment: Of topic: Your multiplication is wrong. The result matrix is not supposed to have the dimension `Mtx2row x Mtx2col`

Comment: @ric.row - you need to fix this question. 1) provide all relevant code, don't give `....` as we can't guess what is and what isn't there and 2) tell which input values you are using (at least the dimensions). As your question is now, it can't be answered and should be closed.

Comment: @4386427 Would like to provide as much info. However, in a short program like this, most code is relevant, but can't post due to Stackoverflow limiting code vs non-code ratio.

Comment: So what does that tell you? (Hint: it is not to provide **less** code!)

Comment: @Olaf To explain more, but how to supplement more description when code is mostly self-explanatory?

Comment: @ric.row - I don't see any initialization of `mult` and still you haven't told about input values. Also I don't see any check for  Mtx1row, Mtx1col, Mtx2row, Mtx2col being <= 10

Answer (score 0):

Two matrices could be multiplied if an only if

```
#columns of the first matrix = #rows of the second matrix.
```

So you need to check this before creating the 2D arrays themselves.

```
if(Mtx1col == Mtx2row){
  //proceed creating the matrices
  int first[Mtx1row][Mtx1col], second[Mtx2row][Mtx2col];
  int mult[Mtx1row][Mtx2col]; // The resulting matrix is Mtx1row * Mtx2col
  // You have variable length arrays(VLAs) above.
}
else{
// put the f/b code here
}
```

**Note**

> Under C11, VLAs are an optional feature rather than a mandatory feature,
>   as they were under C99.
>   The term variable in variable-length array does not mean that you can
>   modify the length of the array after you create it. Once created, a
>   VLA keeps the same size. What the term variable does mean is that you
>   can use a variable when specifying the array dimensions when first
>   creating the array.

---

<sup>The above excerpt is from **Stephen Prata's C++ Primer Plus 6th edition**</sup>

Comment: Nothing wrong with your answer but how does it answer the question?

Comment: @4386427 I put this because the approach itself as mentioned in the question wrong.

Comment: Well, okay ... but it does not address the segmentation fault - anyway it doesn't matter as OP refuse to provide the information needed. Have fun :-)

Answer (score -1):

At least one of your array variables `mult`, `first`, `second` does not provide enough memory for the accesses happening.

When `Mtx2row`, `Mtx2col` and `Mtx1col` have values between 0 and 10 inclusively, the memory accesses should be fine. So please check the value of these variables. As a first step you can just `printf` these values, better would be a programmatic check that precludes out of bounds values. Also, please check that the matrices have compatible dimensions for matrix multiplication, i.e. `Mtx1col` must be equal to `Mtx2row`.

EDIT:

Now that the shown code includes the scanf statements, I can give the following advice. **Always** check the return code of scanf to ensure all arguments have been parsed. You can even add an additional `%c` to ensure there was no extra input. In your case you also have to check if the read array indices are inside the permissible range (here 0-9).